# Cordova platform ios error

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

While running this:

```
fab$ cordova platform add ios
```

I get this error:

> Error during untar for
>
> /Users/fab/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.3.1/package.tgz:
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
> '/Users/fab/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.3.1/package/CordovaLib/.npmignore'
> Error: Failed to fetch platform ios Probably this is either a
> connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Check your
> connection and platform name/version/URL. Error: EACCES: permission
> denied, open
> '/Users/fab/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/4.3.1/package/CordovaLib/.npmignore'

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix

```
 rm -rf ~/.cordova
```